# VB.net Excel.worksheet().cells().Value

Tags: vb.net, excel, vb.net-2010

Trying to write information in Excel worksheet
But have some strange problems ;) i looked info on Google but no result..
So plz help )

I Add reference Microsoft.excel 14.0 Object Library
and also Import Microsoft.Office.interop

I need to get Value from specific cell
so i use command Checker = shXL.cells(1,1). And here i don't have Value....
i only got this (Equal / GetHashCode / GetType / toString)
So question is WHY i don't have (.Value) for .cells and where is an Error

```
        Dim appXL As Excel.Application
        Dim wbXL As Excel.Workbook
        Dim wbsXL As Excel.Workbooks
        Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim Checker As Integer

        appXL = CreateObject("excel.application")
        appXL.Visible = True

        wbsXL = appXL.Workbooks
        wbXL = wbsXL.Open("D:\Некорректные Переключения\Base.xlsx", , , , 12121)
        shXL = wbXL.ActiveSheet
        Checker = shXL.Cells(1, 1).value()
```

Best Regards and THX!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `.Cells()` returns an object.

You can try converting it to a Excel `Cell` object in another step, or you can try this (for example):

```
shXL.Range("A2").Value
```

With conversion will be:

```
Dim xRng As Excel.Range = CType(shXL.Cells(3,3), Excel.Range)
Dim val As Object = xRng.Value()
```

Comment: Also you can use like that:  shXL.Cells(3,3) = "Example text"

Answer (score 4):

With Excel interop, a lot of the time a return value will be in the form of an `Object` so you need to cast to the correct type to get it's actual properties.

So do something like this (my VB is rusty so may not be completely correct)...

```
Dim rng as Excel.Range

rng = CType(shXL.Cells(1, 1), Excel.Range)
Checker = rng.Value
```

Note: I've separated it out into two lines because it's important not use double-dot references with Office interop (e.g., Worksheet.Cell.Value) because you end up with objects you can't release, which will cause issues with Excel not closing properly.

Note2: the `.Value` property also returns as an object so you'll probably want to cast that too

Comment: Hi MrBlue, where can I get more info about the double-dot reference you mention?

Comment: @Ama I haven't used Excel interop in years so can't really point you to a current source (beyond suggesting a Google search).  That said, although it's all over the place it seems this may not be the best advice - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134024/clean-up-excel-interop-objects-with-idisposable/25135685#25135685) from Hans Passant.

Comment: Indeed, from the post you pointed it looks like the double dot rule is nothing but a myth.. !