# Take only a portion of rows in an Excel file

Tags: c#, excel, worksheet

I have an excel sheet with 98 columns and 58 rows
I saw that with code

```
IXLRow row = ws.Row(6);
```

the line takes the A6 column to the last XFD6.
There is the option to take only up to 98 or say to take only the columns are not empty?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're after specifically `IXLRow`, I don't think it's possible. If you're after getting or setting values for the specific range, you might want to check either [Cells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567.aspx) property of the worksheet:

`ws.Cells(1,1)`

or the [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range.aspx) property of the Worksheet:

`ws.Range("A1", "CT58")`

Comment: after I made ws.Range("A1", "CT58")

how I can get the values of the cells?

Comment: By using a `.Value` or `.Value2` property of the Range you get. If you want more specific answer, you need to provide more context to your question. There are examples in the links I have provided. You might also want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004274/vb-net-excel-worksheet-cells-value

Answer (score 0):

Where the range is multiple cells: an array

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range) sheet.get_Range(sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[3,3]);
```

Where range is one cell: a string

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range) sheet.Cells[1, 1];
```