# how to insert a value of an Excel cell into String array in VB.NET?

Tags: arrays, excel, vb.net

i need help , 
i want to insert the value of the excel cell into an array(String array)
how to do that ?

my code:

```
Dim DB_Columns(5) As String 'Columns values Array
Dim i As Integer
Dim tmp_col As String
For i = 0 To 5
    tmp_col = worksheet1.Cells(0, i).value
    DB_Columns(i) = tmp_col
    i = i + 1
Next
```

every time i run the code i got an exception.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23004274/vb-net-excel-worksheet-cells-value

Comment: "i got an exception"  > In your question show that exception as well !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's going to fix your problem as you haven't actually told us what the exception is - but you increment `i` manually in your code even though it's already in a `For` loop. This means you're going to exit the loop early anyway.

Also - `Cells(0, i)` will cause an exception because the `Cells` collection isn't zero-indexed. It expects a row and column index (there isn't a row/column "0").

Finally, you haven't shown us where you assign `worksheet1` - unless you have a reference set to the workbook you will probably need to explicitly qualify it (this is a good habit to get into anyway)

FWIW this is how I would write that code:

```
Dim worksheet1 As Excel.Worksheet = MyXLApp.Workbooks("My Workbook.xlsx").Sheets(1) '// For Example
'// or alternatively something like
'// Dim worksheet1 As Excel.Worksheet = MyXLApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Dim DB_Columns(0 To 5) As String

For i = LBound(DB_Columns) To UBound(DB_Columns)
    DB_Columns(i) = worksheet1.Cells(1, i + 1).value '// Notice I've added 1 to "i" to prevent an exception as rows/columns start from 1
Next
```

You can actually do this without a loop also:

```
Dim DB_Columns() As String

DB_Columns = worksheet1.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value
```

Comment: thanks alot , thats worked for me , its even solved another problems lol :P .

Comment: no worries - you should still consider adding the text from the exception to your original question as it may help others in the future that have the same problem(s)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
tmp_col = worksheet1.Cells.Cells(0, i).value
```

it works for me.

have a nice day.